# Sampling with a random sample size

Tags: probability

Consider drawing balls from an urn containing 10 balls, 5 of which are black. Choose an integer $n$ at random from the set between 1 and 5. Draw $n$ balls from this urn without replacement. What is the probability that all balls will be black?

Comment: You should add the self-study tag as well as complete the question you tried to ask. In addition, tell us what you've tried, what has worked, and what hasn't.

Comment: You didn't finish the question. "Find the probability that all balls in sample will be" doesn't tell us - are you wondering what the probability is that they are all black?

This also seems very much like a homework problem. Again, add the self-study tag to the question and let us know what you have tried and what hasn't worked. We do not simply answer homework problems for people on this site.

Comment: I'm unable to understand what you're attempting to do here. Please explain what you have done and what your thought process is. What you have attempted is unclear - what does $t$ mean? Or $b$, or $n$ or $i$? Please read the rules and frequently asked questions associated with our site here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two random processes in this experiment: the number of balls drawn (uniform discrete n=1 to 5) and the number observed to be black. Conditional on the number of balls drawn, the distribution of black balls drawn follows a hypergeometric probability distribution. However, unconditional on the number of balls drawn this distribution is very complicated.

It is less complicated to apply the law of total probability to obtain the desired probability. In intuitive notation:

Prob(all balls black) = Prob(1 of 1 ball black | 1 ball selected) * Prob(1 ball selected) + Prob(2 of 2 balls black | 2 balls selected) * Prob(2 balls selected) ...